# Handling EC2 Description Rate Limiting In Boto3 Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm creating a Lambda function with the intent of backing up my EC2 instances with their snapshots. However, I noticed reading the boto documentation the call to ec2.describe_instances is rate limited with MaxResults/NextToken. How can I combine the two of these to safely iterate through the list 50 at a time? Below is my work in progress:

```
import boto3
import datetime
import time

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        print("Creating snapshots on " + str(datetime.datetime.today()) + ".")
        maxResults = 50
        schedulers = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name':'tag:GL-sub-purpose', 'Values':[Schedule]}], MaxResults=maxResults)
        nextToken = schedulers['NextToken']
        totalSchedulers = len(schedulers)
        while totalSchedulers == maxResults:
        schedulers = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name':'tag:GL-sub-purpose', 'Values':[Schedule]}], MaxResults=maxResults, NextToken=nextToken)
        nextToken = result['NextToken']
        totalSchedulers = len(schedulers)
        print("Performing backup on " + str(len(schedulers)) + " schedules.")
        successful = []
        failed     = []
        for s in schedulers:
           #[...] More operations here, done 50 at a time.
```

I'm not really sure if I'm using the MaxResults/NextToken parameters correctly or efficiently here. Is this the best way to achieve my desired result/am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate through until `NextToken` is not returned. Here is a sample code to iterate through a batch of instances. Change it to suit your needs.

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
insts = ec2.describe_instances(MaxResults=50)
while True:
  #
  # Process Instances (insts)
  #
  if 'NextToken' not in insts: break
  next_token = insts['NextToken']
  insts = ec2.describe_instances(MaxResults=50, NextToken=next_token)
```